# Google Maps inside a Fragment Activity

Tags: android

I have been using Google Maps via the Google Play Services. I have until now only placed maps inside a Fragment Activity. Can I place a Google MAP object into a layout that will be inflated via a Sherlock Fragment. I mean to ask to place a Fragment in a Fragment ? Is this possible or can the MAP be placed only within a Fragment Activity ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I place a Google MAP object into a layout that will be inflated
>   via a Sherlock Fragment?

If we explore the source of SherlockFragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import com.actionbaronsMenuListener;

public class SherlockFragment extends Fragment implements ...
```

It uses `Fragment` class from support-library so you should use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment` and the answer is 'Yes'.

> I mean to ask to place a Fragment in a Fragment ? Is this possible or
>   can the MAP be placed only within a Fragment Activity ?

You mean nested fragments? Yes, you can put the Map inside the fragment, nested fragment is only supported in `API 16` **but**, support library has this feature.

**Note**: You cannot use static fragments (fragments in layout file) inside the fragment, this is not supported.

Comment: But i use the <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" /> to palce my maps in the layout file ?

Comment: You can create a `SupportMapFragment` programmatically and put this inside the fragment.

Comment: Or I suggest, inflate a layout, and then, put the programmatically created `SupportMapFragment` in the current layout.

Comment: No, sorry but you can search for a tutorial 'android child fragments example'